# border-image implementation for old browser

Tags: html, css

how to implement border-image for old browsers?
I have 8 images:
4 border images (border-top.gif, border-right.gif, border-bottom.gif, border-right.gif)
and 4 border conners (outer part of conners is transparent, it is important) : border-top-left.gif, border-top-right.gif, border-bottom-right.gif, border-bottom-left.gif, also I have next markup:

```
<div class"block">
  <div class="content">A lot of text with images and tables</div>
  <div class="border-top"></div>
  <div class="border-right"></div>
  <div class="border-bottom"></div>
  <div class="border-left"></div>
  <div class="border-top-left"></div>
  <div class="border-top-right"></div>
  <div class="border-bottom-right"></div>
  <div class="border-bottom-left"></div>
</div>
```

any CSS solutions? if it is need I can add classes to markup.
UPD: I know that is easy do with table, but I want find solution for divs.
UPD2: images with gradient, so there is no way to do it without images.

Comment: Are you creating rounded borders? Or just regular borders? I don't see why you couldn't just use border:1px solid #000; for regular... otherwise for round I would suggest http://css3pie.com/ Are all of the images transparent?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at http://cssround.com/

Comment: It really depends on how your border is designed. In most scenarios you won't even need images, but in some there is just no way around it... Also by older browsers I am assuming you mean IE6 and IE7

Comment: thx for cssround.com but top,left,bottoom,right border images have gradient, so this site doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

- relative positioning of your container ( .block )
- absolute positioning of your corner div elements inside the container.

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
    .block { display:block;position:relative; }
    .border-top-left { 
            display:block;
            background-image:url(/folder/topleftcorner.png); 
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            width:10px; height:10px; /* size of your corner graphic above */

            /* this puts it where you want it */
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;

           }
  </style>
  ```

Use from ...

```
        right:0; bottom:0
```

to match up the rest to suit

Comment: I started from it, but i don't know how to put non corner borders, ammm I know how to do it, but top border is visible in transparent part of conners. that problem in :(

Comment: add z-index:1 , z-index:2 to suit -  ( 2 being higher on the page than 1 ) to the css, sounds like you you need to order the ( z-index ) stack order to suit. z-index is our 3rd dimension .. whahayyyy

Comment: so top border should has width = 100% - 32px*2 (32px - size of my corners)

Comment: We don't know what you "top border" is - if you draw it out on a piece of paper and with arrows identify each corner element , it's size and its position you will get a clear idea of what your css needs to do - the absolute positioning and its left, right, bottom and top values are the key.

Comment: z-index doesn't help because outer part of corner images is transparent

Comment: that really is a different question that I tried thought z-index might resolve. Get things where you want them first with the positioning, then look at the presentation issues. To answer your orginal q, the code in the answer is the way you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using CSS sprites. This way you don't have to waste time slicing up images. Allow the CSS background-position declaration do the work for you.

See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

Comment: I know about css sprites, but before using sprites it, i need to do it with out sprites, here will be 3 sprites: 4_conners, top_bottom_border, left_right-border